# Organizing namespaced and related models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm having a bit of trouble organizing a Rails project and its models regarding folder structure and conventions and I don't seem to find anything related to this anywhere.

Let's say I want to create a `Cinema` model, this `Cinema` has many `Cinema::Location` models and each `Cinema::Location`has many `Cinema::Location::Movie` screenings, on top of that each movie might have a `Cinema::Location::Movie::Review`, not to mention each review might have comments...

My folder structure would look something like this:

- app/models/cinema.rb
- app/models/cinema/location.rb
- app/models/cinema/location/movie.rb
- app/models/cinema/location/movie/review.rb
- app/models/cinema/location/movie/review/comment.rb

This is an organized solution, but at the same time, it doesn't look good, it's worse if we talk about the tables (`cinema_location_movie_review_comment_replies`).

One thing I could do is to organize the models like this: `Cinema::Location` for the location and `Location::Movie` for movies, `Movie::Review`for reviews, etc.

Folder structure would look like this:

- app/models/cinema.rb
- app/models/cinema/location.rb
- app/models/location/movie.rb

This solves the problem with the table names (`location_movie` or `movie_review`).

Are there any conventions regarding multi-level namespaced models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you asked yourself why you're nesting your models at all? It looks to me like you're trying to shoehorn namespaces into performing logic that's better left to associations.

If you check out the [ActiveRecord associations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), you'll notice that in the first example, `Book` and `Author` are top-level models -- there's no mention of `Book::Author` or anything like that. There's your convention.

As your application grows more bigger and more complex, cases may arise where model namespacing is appropriate (say, resources specific to different user types), but I don't think it is here.

Comment: How should I approach models that are used to reference only one other model? For example, only a `Cinema` can have many `Location` models and the `Cinema`can have many `Movies` through a `Location`?

Comment: I think I just answered myself here. Thanks!

Comment: Yup :-) also, seems to me `Location` might `has_and_belongs_to_many :movies`, since you may want a many-to-many relationship there (i.e. there are many `movies` at a `location`, but each of those `movies` is shown at many `locations`). Depends on what you're going for in your data model, but seems you're on the right track.